# reload data between two page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to pass data between two page in my app, but my main page reload data only when my app reboot, but my second page print and store my data immediately

this is my second page

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import  {
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
  AsyncStorage,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Navigator,
  TextInput,
  ListView,
  onPress,
  Button,
 Image,
 Text,
View,
  } from 'react-native';


var styles = require('../style.js');

 var count;


class config extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { local: '',
                ext: '',
              };
}

componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("local").then((value) => {
        this.setState({"local": value});
    }).done();
    AsyncStorage.getItem("ext").then((value) => {
        this.setState({"ext": value});
    }).done();
}

  saveData(target, value, i) {
  if (i === 1){
    AsyncStorage.setItem("local", value);
     this.setState({local: value});
  }
   else{
       AsyncStorage.setItem("ext", value);
       this.setState({ext: value});
   }
 }


render(){
return(

  <View>

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image source={require('../../img/mob.png')} style={styles.mob_logo}/>
  </View>

    <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hello From config component</Text>
      <Text>id: {this.props.id}</Text>
      <Text>name: {this.props.name}</Text>
      <Text>name: {this.props.myVar}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.saved}>
          {this.state.local}
      </Text>
        <Text> </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(local) => this.saveData("local",local,1)}
        value={(local) => this.saveData("local",local,1)}
      />

      <Text style={styles.saved}>
          {this.state.ext}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(ext) => this.saveData("ext",ext,2)}
        value={(ext) => this.saveData("ext",ext,2)}
      />
    </View>
    </View>
)
}
}

  module.exports = config;
```

i want to pass local and ext to my 1er page  any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

If two pages doesn't have a parent-child relationship, you have the use the flux architecture to share data between components.

You can use [React-Redux](http://redux.js.org/)